# Is there a way to split and use directly strings from a huge file?

Tags: java, split, stream, streamreader, filesize

I am trying to parse a Huuuge JSON file and to translate it to CSV. The JSON file contains a lot of objects just separated by a ' ' (space).  The objects are not even included in a list '[{...},{...}]'
Here is an object type. In the file, there is thousands of them following each others :
{"name":"cmp1","homepage_url":"http://google.fr","number_of_employees":0.0,"founded_year":0.0,"founded_month":0.0,"founded_day":0.0,"deadpooled_year":0.0,"total_money_raised":"5000"}

Look each character, and find objects in JSON thanks to the number of '{' and '}'.  But this is so slow.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(JsonInputFilePath, "rw");
            int now = 0;
            int open =0;
            int close = 0;
            String currentNode = "";
             long length = raf.length();
            while(length > now) {
                currentNode = currentNode +  (char)raf.readByte();

            raf.seek(now);
                            now++;
            char currentChar = (char)raf.readByte();
            if( currentChar == '{') {
                open ++;
            }
            if( currentChar == '}') {
                close = close +1;
                if(close  == open) {

                    open = 0;
                    close = 0;
                    JsonReader reader = new  JsonReader(new StringReader(currentNode));
                                            //process data with the Json reader -><-

                                    }
                            }
                    }
```

I want to be able to process the data each time a full object is found. It is for a very big file(150mo). So reading everything in one time is not an option.

Comment: Please, add a sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use RandomAccess here, it is just a seq access use case.
2. Implement a simple DFA with a basic stack (level)
3. Separate parsing of file from json parsing

   ```
   public void processObject(String json) {
       System.out.println(json);
   }

   public void read(String file) throws IOException {
       try (FileReader r = new FileReader(file)) {
         int i;
         int level = 0;
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         while((i = r.read()) != -1) {
           char c = (char)i;
           switch(c) {
            case '{':
              sb.append(c);
              level++;
              break;
            case '}':
             sb.append(c);
             level--;
             if (level == 0) {
               processObject(sb.toString());
               sb = new StringBuilder();
             }
             break;
            default:
              if (level > 0) {
                sb.append(c);
              }
              else {
                // Ignore chars between objects
              }
           }
         }
       }
   }
   ```